# Could not detect rake tasks, NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, rubygems

I'm trying to deploy my application to Heroku. (I've never done this before). I initially had a `sqlite` database, but then found out that you have to have a `postgres` database to do so. So i switched everything up, and now when I try to run `git push heroku master` I wind up with this error.  `could not detect rake tasks

When I attempted to run `bundle exec rake -P`, everything seemed to work just fine.

My error logs are

```
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_154932c2286286ad0f0668edbed5dc08/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     ./vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote:  !     ./vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
```

I've gone into herokue settings and set the `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` to `true`

I have the `pg` gem in my gemfile.  (just listed as `gem 'pg'`)

My DB file is

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myDatabase_development
  username: username
  timeout: 5000
  pool: 5

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myDatabase_testing
  username: username
  timeout: 5000


production:
  url:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
  pool: <%= ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
  database: myDatabase_production
  username: username
  timeout: 5000
  pool: 5
```

My production file is

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

When I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, (thinking i have a pre-compiling problem).  everything compiles like it should.

Finally my `application.rb` has only this information in it as well.

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'csv'
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module DowntownInventoryApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

Would anyone have any ideas what i'm missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: What is at `config/application.rb:6`?

Comment: require 'rails/all'

I'll add that file too in case that helps

Comment: in the production DB config, how about changing the keyword from 'url' to 'host'?

Comment: @Fernand sounded like a great idea. I tried making the switch, but no luck. :(

Comment: Now let's see the Gemfile

Comment: run this command to see if it can connect to the DB: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate